# How to sort list using multiple comparators

Tags: c#, comparison

I have sorting problem:

Let's say I have 3 files with the following names:

```
170120_140000_reservation.xml

170120_140001_details_0.xml

170120_140001_details_1.xml
```

The format is [date] _ [time] _ [type] _ [index].xml

(the index is not mandatory)

I need to find a way to sort by 3 conditions:

1. the time-stamp
2. the type (reservation > details, this will pre-defined "strong" type)
3. the index

My current code is as follows:

```
List<FileDate> allFilesData = new List<FileDate>();
//each file is translated into a new "FileDate" object
allFilesData.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Compare(x.timeStamp, y.timeStamp));
```

How can I write compare that will also know to compare by type if the time-stamp is equal, or by index if the time-stamp and the type is equal ?

Comment: you can use `OrderBy` then chain it with `ThenBy` and so forth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more complex functions passed as a lambda for the comparer, for example:

```
allFilesData.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    int c = DateTime.Compare(x.timeStamp, y.timeStamp);
    if (c == 0) {
        c = x.type.Length.CompareTo(y.type.Length);
        if (c == 0)
            return x.index.CompareTo(y.index);
    }
    return c;
});
```

(assuming the type and index are stored in `type` (`string`) and `index` (`int`) members.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a class containing the `date`, the `time` the `type` and the `index` as properties. Then you could LINQ with the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` operators to order the items like required:

```
allFilesData
    .OrderBy(x => x.date)
    .ThenBy(x => x.time)
    .ThenBy(x => x.type)
    .ThenBy(x => x.index);
```

If you need to implement a specific comparison behaviour have a look at the [IComparer Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx).